# Site is down on DRUPAL 7

Tags: drupal

I have access to Drupal and CiviCRM admin but for half the DRUPAL pages I get a white page. (apparently CiviCRM works fine).
Something is crashing the website and I don't understand what.
I still can access to Drupal Logs and they don't show anything special.
I have no idea where to start from.

What is unclear is that I have a drupal multisite functioning with sub folders /site1 /site2 and only 2 from 3 don't work anymore. So this issue is really related to some special parameters I can't find.

Any help?

Comment: Check PHP/apache/nginx error logs

Comment: how? I have access to logs within CiviCRM and Drupal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: I don't have access to these files on my shared hosting :(

Comment: Following this Drupal documentation page https://www.drupal.org/node/158043 I discovered that the issue is Fatal error: Cannot declare class PEAR, because the name is already in use in DRUPAL/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 84. Which module could need PEAR and create a conflict?

Comment: After 10 hours of fighting it works again. Disabling the newly installed module directly inside phpmyadmin did the job.

Comment: Check you dont have two CiviCRM modules running at the same time

Comment: @TonyHorrocks : thanks for your advice. I think there was a mix of 2 CiviCRM modules running + some conflicts with some Drupal module using PEAR.